# Sorting a table that another excel sheet uses causes different VLOOKUP results

Tags: sorting, excel, vlookup, vba

I'm creating a dashboard in Excel 2010 that uses the `VLOOKUP` function to call another sheet's values.

The equation I'm using is this:

> =VLOOKUP(L$1,Sheet_B!$A:$H,7,2)

`L$1` asks for a unique identifier on `Sheet_A`, and then finds that ID on `Sheet_B` and then finds the corresponding data and pulls it.
The problem is this:

If I do nothing to `Sheet_B`, I'll get a value - let's say `5`. This value is *incorrect*.

If I sort `Sheet_B` from A-Z alphabetically (which doesn't change the data) I'll get a totally different value - let's say 12 - which is the *correct* value.

The problem is that the data that the `VLOOKUP` function examines hasn't changed, only how it was sorted in `Sheet_B`.

Is there any reason why this might happen? And more importantly, how can I fix it so I don't have to keep sorting `Sheet_B` every time I pull this dashboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your 4th parameter equals `True` (`2` in your case), `VLOOKUP` tries to find an approximate match, so you need the values in the first column of `table_array` to be placed in ascending order.

If you change it to `0` (equivalent to `False`), `VLOOKUP` will try to find an exact match, and so will not need to be sorted.

Therefore, you should change your `VLOOKUP` to:

```
=VLOOKUP(L$1,Sheet_B!$A:$H,7,0)
```

You can read more [in this Microsoft Office Support article.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-e2fba01b-188c-4057-87e2-df6bb4075817).